# New Apple Mach-O link (id) error

Tags: objective-c, linker-errors

Last night, when I finished working on my project, there were no errors. But today, when I opened my project, I had the Apple Mach-O link (id) error. Here is the error: `Ld /Users/chandlerdeangelis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhereAmI-bdyziqhatjrwffgkgfvwvtoxdroa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WhereAmI.app/WhereAmI normal i386
    cd "/Users/chandlerdeangelis/Desktop/Real Estate App"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/chandlerdeangelis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhereAmI-bdyziqhatjrwffgkgfvwvtoxdroa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/chandlerdeangelis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhereAmI-bdyziqhatjrwffgkgfvwvtoxdroa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/chandlerdeangelis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhereAmI-bdyziqhatjrwffgkgfvwvtoxdroa/Build/Intermediates/WhereAmI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WhereAmI.build/Objects-normal/i386/WhereAmI.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -framework MapKit -framework CoreLocation -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/chandlerdeangelis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhereAmI-bdyziqhatjrwffgkgfvwvtoxdroa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WhereAmI.app/WhereAmI

duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_WhereAmIAppDelegate._window in:
    /Users/chandlerdeangelis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhereAmI-bdyziqhatjrwffgkgfvwvtoxdroa/Build/Intermediates/WhereAmI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WhereAmI.build/Objects-normal/i386/WhereAmIAppDelegate.o
    /Users/chandlerdeangelis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhereAmI-bdyziqhatjrwffgkgfvwvtoxdroa/Build/Intermediates/WhereAmI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WhereAmI.build/Objects-normal/i386/WhereAmIViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_WhereAmIAppDelegate._viewController in:
    /Users/chandlerdeangelis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhereAmI-bdyziqhatjrwffgkgfvwvtoxdroa/Build/Intermediates/WhereAmI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WhereAmI.build/Objects-normal/i386/WhereAmIAppDelegate.o
    /Users/chandlerdeangelis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhereAmI-bdyziqhatjrwffgkgfvwvtoxdroa/Build/Intermediates/WhereAmI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WhereAmI.build/Objects-normal/i386/WhereAmIViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_WhereAmIAppDelegate in:
    /Users/chandlerdeangelis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhereAmI-bdyziqhatjrwffgkgfvwvtoxdroa/Build/Intermediates/WhereAmI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WhereAmI.build/Objects-normal/i386/WhereAmIAppDelegate.o
    /Users/chandlerdeangelis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhereAmI-bdyziqhatjrwffgkgfvwvtoxdroa/Build/Intermediates/WhereAmI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WhereAmI.build/Objects-normal/i386/WhereAmIViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_WhereAmIAppDelegate in:
    /Users/chandlerdeangelis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhereAmI-bdyziqhatjrwffgkgfvwvtoxdroa/Build/Intermediates/WhereAmI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WhereAmI.build/Objects-normal/i386/WhereAmIAppDelegate.o
    /Users/chandlerdeangelis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhereAmI-bdyziqhatjrwffgkgfvwvtoxdroa/Build/Intermediates/WhereAmI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WhereAmI.build/Objects-normal/i386/WhereAmIViewController.o
ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Did you have a chance to check my answer?

Comment: I ended up just copying the code in the files and starting a new project, and the error went away. Thanks you for the help though.

Comment: How do I accept answers? I didn't know what that was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several symbols, (WhereAmIAppDelegate._window, WhereAmIAppDelegate._viewController, ...) are defined duplicate: in *WhereAmIAppDelegate.o* and in *WhereAmIViewController.o*.

A likely cause for this error is that you have imported an ".m" file instead of the ".h" file somewhere. Perhaps you have an `#import "WhereAmIAppDelegate.m"` in *WhereAmIViewController.m*" ?